# Skype command line options

Tags: command-line, skype

The purpose of this question is to get a list of command line options for Skype, as many as possible to get. I know there are more options than the Skype site lists, as is the case with `/secondary` and a list of them would help a lot.

Comment: Parameters are OS dependent. To display skype options list in command line type: skype --help

Answer (score 3):

Per [this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-applications-and-services/0596101899/tweak-and-tune-skype/skypehks-chp-4-sect-5) website and [this](http://www.vasyapupkin.com/skype-command-line-options/) website, the known command line flags for Skype are:

- `/callto [Skype user or telephone number]` - Calls a user or number from Skype
- `/datapath [path]` - Specifies where user personal data is to be stored by Skype
- `/nosplash` - Prevents Skype's splash screen from displaying
- `/minimized` - Launches Skype minimized to the system tray
- `/removable` - Ensures that nonexistent paths aren't written to the Windows registry and does other housekeeping for running Skype from removable media
- `/shutdown` - Stops a running Skype instance

I believe there may be more, but these are all I could find.

Comment: Pretty sure there are more. Found some time ago a page with quite a lot of them and... well, it's lost now.

Comment: @KuraiHikari You may have seen the commands that can be entered in a chat window, such as `/info`.

Comment: @Huskehn I'm pretty certain those were command line options. So careless of me for not saving that page...

Answer (score 3):

Two I'm using to autologin combined with `/secondary`:

- `/username:[your user name]`
- `/password:[your password]`

Comment: Extremely useful, unfortunately tho it's not working anymore as of version 7.16, only the /secondary command.

Comment: +1 for the "not working" - it used to, but the skype 7.18 i installed just now also refuses to sign in with provided credentials. It doesn't even echo them into the login screen username box so I'm reasonably confident that support for these switches has been dropped

Answer (score 0):

This works too (as of May 2015):
/sendto: "C:\path\to\image.jpg"