# How to edit options logged out in Skype for Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, proxy, skype

I need to edit my Skype preferences without logging in, but I don't see "Options" in any menu. What to do?

In my case, I have to edit proxy settings to be able to connect to Skype. There is no environment variable or [command line switch](https://superuser.com/questions/657700/skype-command-line-options) to alter connection options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> from the login screen. You'll be able to edit "advanced options": Skype Wi-Fi and connection options.