# Open multiple Skype instances

Tags: skype, multiple-instances, multiple-users

I managed to use the `/secondary` parameter to run multiple Skype instances.

But when no instance is running and I execute it, it opens with latest profile I used. And when I execute it again, it asks me to login.

Is there a way to create shortcuts that will open an instance and it will be already logged in a profile I choose?

I example, in Pidgin I can use `pidgin.exe -mc <profile path>` and that profile will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to run a macro from the command-line, using a batch script which inserts the log-in details into this secondary Skype session. You'd be able to incorporate `/secondary` within this script file.

This means that you won't be logged in on launch, but the script would go on to log you in automatically prior to the instance launch.

As for having the same account logged in and receiving live updates, in regard to if the first instance has read or seen a message and the second instance following its lead and updating without user interaction. It is to my belief that both the sessions will not work simultaneously in this way.

It goes without saying that there'd be potential security risks through having these details stored in such an open manner.

This article may hold details should you wish to pursue: http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/run_macro_script_from_command_line.html

Comment: hmm yeah I could develop some app to do that, maybe with AutoHotKey and compile it :p But nah not worth it, yet.

Answer (score 2):

`/secondary` parameter is still the way to do it, but I suggest to use more magic from the console.

My case is that I have the main skype account connected to my MS account and the secondary - used for business. Main one should be always online while the secondary only when I'm in the office. Sounds like a perfect place to write some scripts, but what parameters are possible?

There are sources like: ([Skype command line options](https://superuser.com/questions/657700/skype-command-line-options)) and (http://winaero.com/blog/skype-command-line-switches/).

Complete solution using Powershell scripting:

1. Go to `c:\ProgramData` and create folder named `Skype_YOURACCOUNTNAME` - of course you should replace **YOURACCOUNTNAME** phrase with yours.
2. Create file `Start-WorkSkype.ps1`and paste this inside:

   . "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary /nosplash /minimized /username:YOURACCOUNTNAME /password:YOURPASSWORDHERE /removable /datapath:"c:\ProgramData\Skype_YOURACCOUNTNAME\"
3. Create file `Stop-WorkSkype.ps1` and paste this inside:

   . "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary /username:YOURACCOUNTNAME /removable /datapath:"c:\ProgramData\Skype_YOURACCOUNTNAME\" /shutdown
4. You might also place both `Start-WorkSkype.ps1` and `Stop-WorkSkype.ps1` in some folder specified in PATH so they're both runnable from console all the time.

Some comments:

- Directory created in c:\ProgramData could be somewhere else - it's up to you. Just remember that the path goes to **datapath** parameter.
- **/secondary** - explicit declaration that it's not the main one, allowing to open new instance of skype.exe
- **/password** - not required, Skype will ask for it (only **/username** param value will be used)
- **/nosplash** and **/minimized** - self-explanatory params, not needed if you expect different behavior, especially if you would like to enter password every single time
- **/removable** and **/datapath** - make sure the secondary instance is separated from the main one and all its data is stored in some other place
- **/shutdown** - closes specified instance
- Works with Skype 7.29.08.102 and Windows 10 Pro.

If you don't like the console, try this shortcut-based solution: (https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA829/how-can-i-run-multiple-skype-accounts-at-the-same-time)
combined with the parameters I listed above.

Comment: are you able to get the accounts to also automatically login? The first one started up does, but the rest don't (they also lose their language setting and default to system)