# More than 1 instance of Skype working simultaneously on Windows 10 (WindowsApps)

Tags: windows-10, skype

I want to make two instances of Skype working at once (so I have my personal and company accounts online).

I was following the official tutorial: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA829/how-can-i-run-multiple-skype-accounts-at-the-same-time

But in my Windows 10, Skype.exe is inside `‪C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` which is protected even from viewing by administrator.

How can I make more than 1 instance of Skype working on Windows 10 simultaneously?

**Why it's not a duplicate of:**
[Open multiple Skype instances](https://superuser.com/questions/866839/open-multiple-skype-instances)

I want to open multiple instances of Skype on Windows 10 where it's not possible to run it with `/secondary`, the files are re-organized and re-located to WindowsApps (e.g. there is no C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe).

The linked question  is about the old Skype/Windows and does not work for Windows 10 Skype. The problem and approach changed and cannot be applied for new version's situation (despite it works perfectly for the version mentioned in linked question).

Comment: Run the desktop Win32 version of Skype if you want any hope of running multiple instances of it.

Comment: [This](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA829/how-can-i-run-multiple-skype-accounts-at-the-same-time) only works with the Desktop Skype client.  It is currently not possible to run multiple instances of the UWP Skype client.  I might be linking to the same thIn, I wouldn't know, you didn't quote the step your struggling in the body of your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open multiple Skype instances](https://superuser.com/questions/866839/open-multiple-skype-instances)

Comment: The issue is about running Skype APP (windows 10 where app is inside windowsApp folder and not in program files(x86) folder) and that too /secondary is not working.